# set urls with parameter to noindex in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url

I'm looking for a solution to set all URLs which uses the parameter '?' to `noindex`. I look for a php solution which I could use in the `header.php` in Wordpress or in the `.htaccess`.

I tryed this:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if( preg_match('/\?/', $url) ) {
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" />' . "\n";
}
?>
```

This solution did not work and URLs with the parameter '?' didn't get a `noindex` attribute.

Best regards

Comment: `strpos()` instead of `preg_match()`?

Comment: nothing happens...:-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strpos()` function for that:

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strpos($url,'?') !== false) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" />' . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. should i use this code for wordpress in the header.php or in the functions.php??

Comment: because you want to add additional `meta` tag, is quite enough to do it in your `header.php` where usually is placed `<head>` part.